# Infowindow is not displaying on marker cluster

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I am trying to show infowindow on marker cluster when marker is clicked.But its not working.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/302j8csd/3/

```
var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: location,
          label: labels[i % labels.length]
        });

        marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });

        return marker;
      });
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: fiddle is not working. have you checked it?

Comment: @HardikSavani please check now.

Comment: How re you trying to show an infowindow on the markercluster when a marker is clicked?  What marker are you clicking?  You can't click on the ones in the cluster and the ones that aren't in the cluster have their own infowindows.  I would have thought you would want to open an infowindow on the markercluster when the **cluster** is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to give map height and width through css,

here is complete code,

**Html**

```
<div id="map-view"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#map-view{
  height:500px;
  width:500px;
}
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    initialization() 
});

function initialization() {

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-view'), {
        zoom: 3,
        center: {lat: 19.317779, lng: -91.459656},
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
      });
      map.setTilt(45);


      var labels = 'KLMNOPQRS';

      var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
          '<div id="siteNotice">'+
          '</div>'+
          '<h2 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">BMW 7 Series</h2>'+
          '<div id="bodyContent">'+
          '<p>Details goes here</p>' +
          '</div>';

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
      });


      var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: location,
          label: labels[i % labels.length]
        });

        marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });

        return marker;
      });


      var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
          {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
    }

var locations = [
{lat: 12.7781453358752, lng: -82.3715011598119},
{lat: 44.0026085052726, lng: -81.4873632217882},
{lat: 74.0086085052726, lng: -81.6873632217882}
];
```

Comment: why should we add width and height? my question is infowindow?

Comment: infowindo was opening, but the problem was map was not showing, so i give height and width to map, and decrease zoom to 3, info window was already working

Comment: what exactly you want, its working for me, infowindow is opening on above fiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152726/discussion-between-muhammad-akber-khan-and-user7397787).